# Marionette router is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I cannot run the code below because **router is undefined** in my view. However I'm struggling to understand where I actually defined `var router = new MyRouter();` my view, controller app start etc?

I'm using **marionette** and my router seems to automatically match my controllers.

```
success: function (page) {
   id = page.get('id')
   router.navigate('page/' + id, {trigger: true});
}
```

Comment: Is there a router property on your App instance? I seem to remember that was the convention with Marionette. Where do you define the method in your question? Is it in a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't declare a `router` attribute, you don't have one available (it doesn't get created automatically or anything), hence the `undefined` value.

To navigate to a given page, you can also use `Backbone.history.navigate` (see for example https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/app.js).

In addition, you might want to reconsider using the `trigger: true` option, per the reasons explained [here](http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf) (Routing chapter) in the free sample to my [book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction).

Comment: thank you for your answer I will check out the books